# Browse to Sharepoint folder

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, sharepoint

In Excel VBA, I'm using the code below to browse to a folder. But it doesn't see SharePoint folders. How can I browse to SharePoint folders?

I do see that I could ask the user to map a drive to SharePoint, and then the code would see the mapped drive. I also see that I could programmatically map the drive if I get the user to provide a SharePoint path as a text string. But is it possible to just browse to it without asking the user to provide anything at all?

Here's the code I'm using to browse folder. This is from Chip Pearson's website, just converted to 64-bit Excel:

```
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS As Long = &H1
Private Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN As Long = &H2
Private Const BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS As Long = &H8
Private Const BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER As Long = &H1000
Private Const BIF_BROWSEFORPRINTER As Long = &H2000
Private Const BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES As Long = &H4000
Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Type BrowseInfo
    hOwner As LongPtr
    pidlRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszINSTRUCTIONS As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As LongPtr
    lParam As LongPtr
    iImage As Long
End Type

Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hwnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAnyOperationsAborted As Boolean
    hNameMappings As Long
    lpszProgressTitle As String
End Type

Declare PtrSafe Function SHGetPathFromIDListA Lib "shell32.dll" ( _
    ByVal pidl As LongPtr, _
    ByVal pszBuffer As String) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function SHBrowseForFolderA Lib "shell32.dll" ( _
    lpBrowseInfo As BrowseInfo) As LongPtr



Function BrowseFolder(Optional Caption As String = "") As String

Dim BrowseInfo As BrowseInfo
Dim FolderName As String
Dim ID As LongPtr
Dim Res As Long

With BrowseInfo
   .hOwner = 0
   .pidlRoot = 0
   .pszDisplayName = String$(MAX_PATH, vbNullChar)
   .lpszINSTRUCTIONS = Caption
   .ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS
   .lpfn = 0
End With

FolderName = String$(MAX_PATH, vbNullChar)
ID = SHBrowseForFolderA(BrowseInfo)
If ID Then
   Res = SHGetPathFromIDListA(ID, FolderName)
   If Res Then
       BrowseFolder = Left$(FolderName, InStr(FolderName, vbNullChar) - 1)
   End If
End If

End Function



Function test__BrowseFolder()
    Dim FName As String
    FName = BrowseFolder(Caption:="Select A Folder")
    If FName = vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print "No Folder Selected"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Selected Folder: " & FName
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why not just map it to a network drive? One time and done. Then hard code the UNC path in the code. One time setup versus the complicated process of figuring out how to do it programmatically. (I am saying this based on experience of trying to do the same thing).

Comment: Scott Holtzman, thanks, but wouldn't different organizations have different SharePoint paths? If I hardcode it for one organization's SharePoint path, wouldn't that break with other organizations with different SharePoint paths?

Comment: Yes. In that case you can create an input cell where the user provides the sharepoint folder to map the drive too and the code will map it. If this will go across different organizations, I don't see anyway to avoid user input on the mapping.

Comment: What's the rationale for passing `BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS`? Did you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115.aspx)?

Comment: Scott, thanks, I'll go ahead and do that. But just out of curiosity, is there really no way to get it without manual user input?

Comment: IInspectable, as I said, "This is from Chip Pearson's website, just converted to 64-bit Excel". In other words, this is mostly boilerplate code. All I did was convert it from 32-bit to 64-bit.

Comment: Is a SharePoint folder a genuine file system object?